# modifying python code to make it 'importable'

Tags: python, object, import

I've been trying to modify the code below so I can import the lcd class and call the writeLCD function as a function call on an object in another class. I'm stuck at the moment because when i try 'import lcd' the python interpreter, it errors and says driver1 is not defined in the line

`self.lcd1 = HD47780(driver1, rows=2, width =16)`

```
import time

class LCD_23017(object):
    # Timing constants
    E_PULSE = 0.00005
    E_DELAY = 0.00005

    def __init__(self, bus, addr, port, rs, en):
        self.bus = bus
        self.addr = addr
        self.rs = rs
        self.en = en

      self.DIRECTION = 0x00 if port == 'A' else 0x01
      self.DATA = 0x12 if port == 'A' else 0x13

      self.bus.write_byte_data(addr, self.DIRECTION, 0x00)

def lcd_byte(self, data, rs):
    rs <<= self.rs
    en = 1 << self.en
    for nybble in (data&0xf0, data<<4):
        self.bus.write_byte_data(self.addr, self.DATA, nybble | rs)
        time.sleep(self.E_DELAY)
        self.bus.write_byte_data(self.addr, self.DATA, nybble | rs | en)
        time.sleep(self.E_PULSE)
        self.bus.write_byte_data(self.addr, self.DATA, nybble | rs)


class HD47780(object):
    LCD_CHR = True
    LCD_CMD = False
    # Base addresses for lines on a 20x4 display
    LCD_BASE = 0x80, 0xC0, 0x94, 0xD4

    def __init__(self, driver, rows=2, width=16):
        self.rows = rows
        self.width = width
        self.driver = driver
        self.lcd_init()

    def lcd_init(self):
        # Initialise display
        lcd_byte = self.driver.lcd_byte
        for i in 0x33, 0x32, 0x28, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x01:
            lcd_byte(i, self.LCD_CMD)

    def lcd_string(self, message, line=0):
        # Send string to display
        lcd_byte = self.driver.lcd_byte
        lcd_byte(self.LCD_BASE[line], self.LCD_CMD)
        for i in bytearray(message.ljust(self.width)):
            lcd_byte(i, self.LCD_CHR)


class lcd:
    def __init__(self, smbus):
    driver1 = LCD_23017(bus=smbus.SMBus(0), addr=0x20, port='B', rs=0, en=1)
    # driver2 = LCD_23017(bus=smbus.SMBus(1), addr=0x20, port='B', rs=0, en=2)

    self.lcd1 = HD47780(driver1, rows=2, width=16)
    # lcd2 = HD47780(driver=driver2, rows=2, width=16)




def writeLCD(self, line, message):
    self.lcd1.lcd_string(message, line)
    # lcd2.lcd_string("     London")



#def main():
#    test_i2c()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Where's the import? Please show the actual code that you use. Also the above code will generate an error since `main()` is commented out.

Comment: thanks, removing the if __name__ == "__main__": .... fixed the error